# Forwarding nginx to an Openfire XMPP local server

Tags: nginx, xmpp, openfire

I have an already existing nginx server that is a reverse proxy to my internal network, How do I configure it to proxy forward traffic from NGINX to an Openfire XMPP local server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include stream module on Nginx config

```
load_module '/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so';
stream {

    server {
        listen 5222;
        proxy_protocol on;
        proxy_pass 192.168.X.X:5222;
    }
    server {
        listen 5223;
        proxy_protocol on;
        proxy_pass 192.168.X.X:5223;
    }


}
```